# React/Redux: How to async or something else?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-redux

***Hello Everyone,
need your help today with filtering in Redux...***

[image]

I have filter (you can see on a picture) with several inputs (filters) for my search.
In order to receive **Fleet** information (filter) I need to pass an **"ID"** form **Client**...

```
const clientChange = (event) => {
  const client = event.target.value;
  const client_id = client.id;
  dispatch({ type: "CLIENT_LIST_SELECTION", payload: client_id });
  getFleetFilter();
};
```

That's my function **clientChange** in **Form.js**

```
const client_id = useSelector((state) => state.client.selection);
const getFleetFilter = async () => {
  dispatch({ type: "FLEET_LIST_REQUEST" });
  try {
    let res = await getFleet(token, client_id);
    let data = res.data.data
    dispatch({ type: "FLEET_LIST_LOAD", payload: data });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error Fleet Data");
      console.log(err);
    };
  };
};
```

That's my function **getFleetFilter** in **Search.js**

***Problem:*** I have undefined **client_id** in API string, because, function **getFleetFilter** getting called quicker, than **client_id** getting stored in Redux!

***Question:*** How can I avoid this keeping using Redux here ?

***Thank you!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the useEffect callback for this like so:

```js
const client_id = useSelector((state) => state.client.selection);

useEffect(() => {
  if (client_id) {
    getFleetFilter();
  }
}, [client_id]);

const clientChange = (event) => {
  const client = event.target.value;
  const client_id = client.id;
  dispatch({ type: "CLIENT_LIST_SELECTION", payload: client_id });
};

const getFleetFilter = async () => {
  dispatch({ type: "FLEET_LIST_REQUEST" });
  try {
    let res = await getFleet(token, client_id);
    let data = res.data.data
    dispatch({ type: "FLEET_LIST_LOAD", payload: data });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error Fleet Data");
      console.log(err);
    };
  };
};
```